# What is the best practice to use nested AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nested, readability

In my Android app I have up to 4 asynchronous tasks that depend on each other, which means that one task has to finish before the next one can go one with the retreived data. Now this can be quite unclear at some point when the code looks something like this:

```
final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> taskOne = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {   
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // retrieve required data   
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        if (success) {
            // start second task here
            final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> taskTwo = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // retrieve required data   
                    return true;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
                    if (success) {
                        // start third task here
                        final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> taskThree = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                super.onPreExecute();
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                // retrieve required data   
                                return true;
                            }

                            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
                                if (success) {
                                    // and so on ...
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        taskThree.execute();
                    }
                }
            }

            taskTwo.execute();
        }
    }
}

taskOne.execute();
```

What would be the best practice to achieve this behaviour with a more readable code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create three seprate class and in onPostExecute() you just need to call that another class like new TaskTwo().execute()

Comment: Or you can use just one class, but, depending on your previous response,  pass different params in the constructor.

Comment: Would recommend you take a look at using `RxJava` for something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TaskOne**

```
Class TaskOne extends AsyncTask{

  onPostExecute(boolean success){
     if(success){
        new TaskTwo().execute();
     }
  }
}
```

**TaskTwo**

```
Class TaskTwo extends AsyncTask{

  onPostExecute(boolean success){
     if(success){
        new TaskThree().execute();
     }
  }
}
```

**TaskThree**

```
Class TaskThree extends AsyncTask{

      onPostExecute(boolean success){
         if(success){
            //do something
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using your approach and it is working just like it should. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should crash with Interface. In your case it's called Listener or Callback. I didn't test the code. But it looks like that

```
    Class A extend Activity implement ServerRequestListener{


          public ServerRequestListener listener;

          @Override 
          onCreate (Bundle bundle){
               listener = this;
               doTaskOne();
          }

          public void doTaskOne(){
               final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> taskOne = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {   
                     @Override
                     protected void onPreExecute() {
                         super.onPreExecute();
                     }

                     @Override
                     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                         // retrieve required data   
                         return true;
                     }

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
                         if (success) {
                             listener.onSuccess(new JSON());
                         }
                     }
            }

            taskOne.execute();

        }



         public interface ServerRequestListener {
               void onSuccess(Json);
               void onFailure(Error);
         }


         @Override
         onSuccess(Json json){
             //call second task
         }

         @Override
         onFailure(Error error){

         }

    }
```